# Unable to run Fuseki as a service

Tags: linux, ubuntu, service, fuseki

I unpacked `fuseki` distribution in `/etc/default/fuseki`. 
As long as I try to run it with `sudo service fuseki start` it outputs

```
* Could not see Fuseki .jar file: $FUSEKI_START has value '/etc/init.d/fuseki-server.jar'
```

I tried also to set `FUSEKI_HOME` with no luck.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by creating the file

```
/etc/default/fuseki
```

containing

```
FUSEKI_HOME=/path/to/fuseki
```

Answer (score 0):

i used Fuseki a long time ago, but i have saved a .sh in my github, i will paste him here, i think will help you.

i used fuseki with apache jena:

```
#linux ubuntu
#uhull Tiago RDF# jena install
#https://jstirnaman.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/installing-fuseki-with-jena-and-tdb-on-os-x/
:'tretas para instalar e utilizar'
mkdir apache
cd apache/
wget www.apache.org/dist/jena/binaries/apache-jena-3.0.0.tar.gz
tar -zxvf apache-jena-3.0.0.tar.gz
wget www.apache.org/dist/jena/binaries/apache-jena-fuseki-2.3.0.tar.gz
tar -zxvf apache-jena-fuseki-2.3.0.tar.gz
clear
:'download completo'
cd apache-jena-3.0.0
export JENAROOT=[/path_to_apache-jena-3.0.0]
export PATH=$PATH:$JENAROOT/bin
cd ..
cd apache-jena-fuseki-2.3.0
export JENAROOT=[/path_to_apache-jena-3.0.0]
export PATH=$PATH:$JENAROOT/bin
cd ..
sparql --version
cd apache-jena-fuseki-2.3.0/
chmod +x fuseki-server
cd bin/
chmod +x s-*
#http://www.theinfohunger.com/install-jena-fuseki/
grep -r "fuseki-server" apache-jena-fuseki-2.3.0/
cd apache-jena-fuseki-2.3.0/
./fuseki-server --update --mem /ds
firefox http://localhost:3030/ &
ls -lai
#mkdir ./DB
#./fuseki-server --update --loc=DB /ds
#rdfxml --validate ./Data/bibapp_works.rdf
#./s-put -v http://localhost:3030/ds/data default ./Data/bibapp_works.rdf
:'PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
```

:' are Comments, ignore

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/h31nr1ch/RaspberryPi/master/RDF3x/jenash.sh